# how many shards are proper for each collections in solr?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a Solr cloud (version 7.4) with 2 nodes (each one has 10Gb SSD hard and 256Gb memory and 50Gb heap) and 10 collections.

one collection has **12** billion documents and rest of collections has **1** billion documents.

we don’t know exactly how many shards are proper for my use case.

How can I determine the appropriate number of shaders and How many Shard is appropriate for each collection?

Does it have a formula?

Comment: No. Especially not with a non-trivial corpus like the one you are outlining: https://lucidworks.com/2012/07/23/sizing-hardware-in-the-abstract-why-we-dont-have-a-definitive-answer/

Answer (score 1):

Shards should be located on different hardware for optimal performance (that's why you shard). Right now with 2 nodes you pretty much should pick 2 shards. But for the performance you are after you might need more nodes and add more shards.

Naturally performance is not just a factor of the number of shards / nodes but also how much memory each node has (heap and off-heap), CPU, you read/write mix, network speed, disk I/O speed etc. not to mention autoCommit / autoSoftCommit settings compared to the size of the index and your expected load.

Comment: You shard to get parallel processing of multiple smaller data sets, as opposed to (practically) sequential processing of a single large data set. That is often done with multiple smaller machines, but if you have a big iron, it is perfectly fine for handling multiple shards. We do it locally with 25 shards of 300M documents per server: It is logistically easier and overall cheaper for us.

Comment: Fair enough you'll just have to make sure you have a big fat "pipe" to your disk and the disk(s) can handle the I/O :-)